# Using 3rd party library typings with Angular CLI

Tags: typescript, angular, angular-cli

I am trying to figure out how to use various 3rd party libraries within Angular CLI environment. The official [wiki page](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/3rd-party-libs) was very useful to get going with moment.js lib. However, I ran into trouble when trying to install *typings* for the library (step 1a in the tutorial):

```
typings install moment --save

typings WARN hastypings Typings for "moment" already exist in 
"node_modules/moment/moment.d.ts". You should let TypeScript resolve
the packaged typings and uninstall the copy installed by Typings

typings ERR! message Unable to find "moment" ("npm") in the registry.
Did you want to try searching another source? Also, if you want contribute
these typings, please help us: https://github.com/typings/registry
```

My setup for reference:

```
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.5
node: 4.4.4
os: darwin x64
typings: 1.0.5
```

Although the error message suggests to "uninstall the copy installed by Typings" it seems that there is no new `.d.ts` files added to the project folder. What would be the best way to include 3rd party typings in this case?

Comment: Have you solved your problem ? which version of angular2 you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Run `npm install @types/moment`.

Explanation:

You've got at least a couple problems here.

(1) As the TypeScript team [announced](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/), "getting type declarations in TypeScript 2.0 will require **no tools apart from npm**" (emphasis theirs). This means that `typings` [has been deprecated](https://github.com/typings/typings#deprecation-notice-regarding-typescript20), and npm *alone* is needed to install typing files. A simple example would be `npm install --save @types/lodash`. Take note of `@types`. All typings now go in `node_modules/@types`. With this in mind, we can look at your second problem.

(2) You're using `typings`, a TypeScript 1 tool, with `angular-cli`, which uses TypeScript 2. They aren't compatible. Instead, you can install `momentjs`'s typings with `npm install @types/moment`.

Finally--and not directly related to your question--you may be interested in [angular2-moment](https://github.com/urish/angular2-moment), an open source library that ports `momentjs` to Angular 2.